# React Ref with Class Component issue

Tags: reactjs, class, ref

[Child Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDpga.jpg)

[Parent Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnYaV.jpg)

Here I get an issue that My parent Component isn't able to access child Component ref when I click  button. It calls the method clickHandler by clicking on button but It shows an error:

Error: focusInput is not defined...

I got stuck in this problem. Kindly guide me where I am wrong.
Thanks!

I want to solve my React ref concept but I got stuck

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. You'll need to post a minimal example that would allow reproducing the problem.

Comment: And if you for some strange reason need to post a screenshot, learn how to take a screenshot. Definitely never take pictures of the screen with a camera. That's just awful and will definitely make people to skip helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react you cannot directly pass ref down the DOM tree, just like the way you pass down props to child components. In order to pass ref you need to use React.forwardRef

Please consider reading the [docs of forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: Okay Thanks! I saw a tutorial actually which tells us this way to implement ref with Class.